# Write HQL UPDATE query with generic type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hql

I have a generic tokenRepository interface :

```
public interface TokenRepository<T_Token extends Token, T_id> {

   @Modifying
   @Query("UPDATE T_token as a SET a.revocationReason = :reason WHERE a.id = :id")
   void revokeByTokenId (@Param("id") T_id id, @Param("reason") RevocationReason revocationReason);

}
```

And a specialized repository interface :

```
public interface CustomerTokenRepository extends Repository<CustomerToken, Long>, TokenRepository<CustomerToken, Long> {}
```

When I launch the Spring Boot app, hibernate return the following error :

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: T_token is not mapped [UPDATE T_token as a SET a.revocationReason = :reason WHERE a.id = :id]
```

So my question is : Is it possible and how to use java generic type with HQL ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible

```
@Modifying
   @Query("UPDATE #{#entityName} as a SET a.userRevocationReason = :reason WHERE a.refreshToken.id = :rid")
   void revokeByRefreshToken (@Param("rid") T_id refreshTokenId, @Param("reason") UserRevocationReason userRevocationReason);
```

Where entity name is `@Entity(name = "my_entit_name")`

Comment: Thanks ! Is ```@Entity(name = "my_entit_name")``` must be on the CustomerToken entity ? Where can I found this in HQL documentation ```#{#entityName}``` ?

Comment: Yes, I have read this here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details the section is 5.3.7. Using SpEL Expressions

Comment: Ensure that the base interface repository is annotated with @NoRepositoryBean